# Merge conflicts in all existing pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, git, merge, egit

I am working in my own git-branch in a big project. Once I have a stable feature I send a pull request to get my updates into `master`.

Other colleagues however have their own branches and we have a blessed repo that we merge into our own branch to have the current newest stable global state.

Now here is the problem: When I fetch and then merge the blessed repo into my own branch, then I encounter a merge conflict (A prompt opens and just states -> conflicting)

Now the issue is that this happens for all the `pom.xml` (basically my whole project explorer is glowing red with merge conflicts in all the `pom.xml`, **even on ones I never touched and are not relevant for my files**)

If I open a `pom.xml` there are merge annotations like `<----- HEAD` and so on.

Now how do I resolve this? Do I really have to manually go into each and every file and edit this? Can't I just have the merge overwrite all my stuff ... except for the few classes I edited?

Comment: When was the last time you merged prior to this attempt?  Do you have an editor that is formatting files (or otherwise making whitespace changes) without your knowledge?  Can you show a diff for a file you never touched that is in conflict?

Comment: I have seen projects where after you release the code from Jenkins, a script goes and bumps the version #in pom file and auto commits it. May be it's the same case with your project in which case the pom versions in your branch can go out of sync with your colleagues branch which can cause merge conflicts.

Comment: (Take a look particularly at the third answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7589612/2003763 )

Comment: @BrandonMcKenzie: Last time was 10 days ago. Also I can confirm that there has been no whitespace changes to my files and the pom.xml

Comment: @VishalKamat Seems like this is indeed related to the pom.xml version, can this not be automated somehow?

Comment: Not sure about automated process to avoid this situation but given this happened, you can do git checkout --ours '*/pom.xml' to choose your pom file to resolve the conflicts. If you want to use their version then instead of --ours use --theirs

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. In the end it was really the versioning that was *outdated* over multiple pom.xml ... this can be considered solved.